# VSTO: Forcing Save Dialogue to appear when an addin custom ribbon button is clicked which updates only a Form region

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, ribbon, region

Using VSTO to create an Outlook Addin, with a custom ribbon and a Form Region.

When I click one of the custom buttons, the region is updated. I need the item (MailItem or AppointmentItem)  to know it's been modified so a "do you want to save" dialogue pops up.

I see there is a Saved property, but it's readonly (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.saved ) is there a way to safely trigger it without a hack (e.g. not item.Subject = item.Subject)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Outlook Object Model, modifying any property will mark the item as dirty. Are you not modifying the item?

BTW, resetting the `Subject` property might not be safe as it can wipe out the conversation id. You can reset the `MessageClass` property instead.

Comment: Yes, subject is dangerous. it can wipe itself out if it doesn't lose focus when clicking a custom ribbon button!

Comment: What do you mean "You can reset the MessageClass"? Things like item.MessageClass = item.MessageClass or item.MessageClass = null don't seem to do anything.

Comment: Something like `oldMessageClass = item.MessageClass;  item.MessageClass = "IPM.Note.Test"; item.MessageClass = oldMessageClass;`